# parsing fb2 book as xml

Tags: c#, xml, fb2

I want to write a fb2 book parser. I am trying to parse it like xml in this way:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("file name");

foreach(XmlNode item in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
    using(StreamWriter sw=new StreamWriter("text.txt"))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting unreadable set of letters. Also I have a question: If the book contains an image, how should I get it correctly?

Comment: have you read this? http://gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/index.html.en

Comment: The image needs to be convert to a string.  An image consists of binary (0x00 - 0xFF) and not all binary characters are ASCII Text.  So you need to use Convert.ToBase64String().